# Quickest way to find out heroku database size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

What is the quickest way to find out the **current** size of my shared database in Heroku?

Comment: they did! I hope this is a mistake and not a new deliberate practice.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

running `heroku info` shows:

```
Data size:      480k
Addons:         Basic Logging, Shared Database 5MB
```

Data size being the size of the shared database, here with a limit of 5MB.

Comment: Right, but that is the max size of the database.  The whole point is that I want to see how close I am getting to that number.

Comment: Currently it shows `Data size:` row with the actual size of the database

Comment: That is right; it must have changed. Maybe this answer should be edited to reflect the attribute's correct name?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, see @Josh 's answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350733/1252307

Answer (score 46):

From the same doc page as posted by nate c:

```
heroku pg:info
```

This only seems to work if you're not using the shared DB, but using PG as an add-on

Also, make sure your heroku gem is up to date:

```
sudo gem update heroku
```

Any ideas on how to see the size of a shared db?  I just did a heroku db:pull and then a mysqldump and looked at the file size, figured that was a good rough estimate.

Comment: It works for our shared database:  Data size    17.1MB, and that is the same information as returned by the `heroku info` command.

Answer (score 13):

The new way seems to be:

```
heroku pg:info -a myapp
```

You'll see something like:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.1.5
Created:     2012-10-19 01:27 UTC
Data Size:   12.1 MB
Tables:      31
Rows:        36068/10000 (Above limits, access disruption imminent)
Fork/Follow: Unavailable
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on Nate's answer:

For **shared** DB w/o installing Postgres on your local machine

```
heroku console

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('postgres'))").first
```

'postgres' is the name of my shared DB, when I put in template0 or template1 I get the same number back.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for... thanks!, in production I get this error though: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  permission denied for database postgres
: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('postgres'))

Comment: There is a function named current_database() that will return the name of whatever database you're actually connected to.  So the query "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database()))" will return a value for whatever database you connect to is, which is probably the one you care about.

Answer (score 6):

You can log into Posgtgresql directly.

type `heroku pg:psql`.

But you have to have postgres on your local system as well so you can use `pgsql` (which is the command line interface for pg.)

If you do not know what the db name is then type `\l in` pgsql to list databases. (postgres, template0, and template1 are system databases in every install.)

Then 
`SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('dbname'));`

Comment: And how exactly would I call this? From the heroku console?

Comment: From their docs at http://docs.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql#local-postgresql-installation$ heroku pg:psql

Comment: Ignore above (edit timed out) From their docs at http://docs.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql#local-postgresql-installation$  Then type: 'heroku pg:psql'. But you have to have postgres on your local system as well so you can use 'pgsql' (which is the command line interface for pg.) If you do not know what the db name is then type \l in pgsql to list databases. (postgres, template0, and template1 are system databases in every install.)

Comment: Great, thanks! Maybe you could edit that comment into the main answer for others?

Answer (score 1):

In heroku postgres panel you can see everything  https://postgres.heroku.com/